# How to detect orientation in costomNavigationbar?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

i need to draw PortraitImage or LandscapeImage when my costomNavigation has been change to portrait or landscape.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: in your UIViewController. This will give you a call every time the app changes its orientation.

Comment: did you mean UIViewController must send message to norify my customNavigationbar ?

Comment: well, if you override that method in your UIViewController you will get a notice when the orientation changes and you can then do with that what you want depending on your apps architecture... but sending a message to your customNavigationbar would probably make sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect orientation by using the UIDevice Class, as shown here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/orientation

You need to use the methods

```
- (void)beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications
```

and

```
- (void)endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications
```

That should probably work.